# UIButton cannot be displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c

in my app i'm using a scroll View (paging). each view in the scroll view (UIImageView) contains an image and each image has tags (buttons) scattered all over the pic. so here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.pictures.count; i++)
    {
        //The first loop is to loop to every picture
        int nbOfTags = classObject.tagsImages.count;

        for (int j = 0; j < nbOfTags; j++)
        {
            //Second loop is to loop to each tag corresponding to the picture

            ListTags *listTags = [[ListTags alloc]init];

            NSMutableArray *tagInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            listTags = [tagInfo objectAtIndex:j];

            float tagX = [listTags.tag_x floatValue];
            float tagY = [listTags.tag_y floatValue];
            float x = 1024*i+ tagX;
            float y = tagY;

            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x, tagY, 20, 20);
            UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

            UIImage * buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueCircle.png"];

            [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            [self.scrollView addSubview:button];
        }
    }
```

problem: when i run the code i can't see the buttons (tags) on the picture. if i replace "i" with "j" in

> float x = 1024*i+ tagX;

the buttons can be seen, however it's not the desired coordinates. so why "i" can't work? am i doing anything wrong or missing anything?

Comment: What is the value of i in the calculation if you check with a breakpoint?

Comment: Try NSLog(@"1024*%i + %f = %f", i, tagX, 1024*i+tagX) after float y = tagY;

Comment: i checked with the breakpoint and the value does change from 0 to the numbers of pictures.

Comment: @LeonardPauli tried it the coordinates are as the one i want!

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder (or storyboard - IB) uncheck autolayout (if it's checked) then your button will be displayed where you want.

Answer (score 0):

See my comments in the code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.pictures.count; i++)
    {
        //The first loop is to loop to every picture
        /* 
         * This will give you the same number of tags for every image. 
         * Is that what you want? 
         */
        int nbOfTags = classObject.tagsImages.count;

        for (int j = 0; j < nbOfTags; j++)
        {
            //Second loop is to loop to each tag corresponding to the picture

            /* This allocates a brand new ListTags object EVERY time through the loop. */
            ListTags *listTags = [[ListTags alloc]init];

            /* This allocates a brand new EMPTY array EVERY time through the loop. */
            NSMutableArray *tagInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            /* 
             * This discards the new ListTags object that you just created two lines ago
             * and replaces it with an object from tagInfo.  Which doesn't exist because
             * you just created a new array in the previous line.  This really should
             * crash, which leads me to believe that this isn't the actual code that you
             * are using.  Post the actual code that you are using so that we can help you
             * better. 
             */
            listTags = [tagInfo objectAtIndex:j];

            /* None of this is valid since listTags is nil/we never should have gotten here. */
            float tagX = [listTags.tag_x floatValue];
            float tagY = [listTags.tag_y floatValue];
            float x = 1024*i+ tagX;
            float y = tagY;

            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x, tagY, 20, 20);
            UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

            UIImage * buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueCircle.png"];

            [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            [self.scrollView addSubview:button];
        }
    }
```